# Including search term in paging in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Been pulling my hair out for about an hour now. How can I keep the search term for a paginated result set in the links (like page numbers) etc

Here is the code that creates the pagination (no other pagination related code anywhere else)

```
   $this->paginate = array (
   'conditions' => array('status ' => '0', 'OR' => array ( 'country LIKE' => $_GET['search'],  'administrative_area_level_1 LIKE' => $_GET['search'],  'locality LIKE' => $_GET['search'],  'sublocality_level_1 LIKE' => $_GET['search'],  'name LIKE' => '%' . $_GET['search'] .'%'  )) );
```

$data = $this->paginate('Segment');

However, the GET variable is not included in any of the paging links so when I click one the search term disappears.

The URL where the above code lives is: http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/main/segmentsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the view before the page numbers or next-previous links

```
    $paginator->options(
       array('url' => array('controller' => 'competitions','action' => 'competitionList','?'=>'search='.$_GET['search'])
    );

echo $paginator->prev('<< Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
                        echo $page_no;
                        echo $paginator->next(' Next >>', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
```